# android ProgressDialog: setting custom view instead of message - does this work?

Tags: android, view, progressdialog

In ProgressDialog's documentation it says:

"A dialog showing a progress indicator and an optional text message or view. Only a text message or a view can be used at the same time."

I've gotten it working beautifully with a message, but I want to use a custom view instead - a message with a cancel button.  But calling setView() on the ProgressDialog seemingly has no effect - it shows the progress bar in the dialog but nothing else.  I've tried it with just a TextView with the text "hello", but it doesn't show up.

Does anyone know how to get this feature to work?  Is it a real feature?

Answer (score 2):

A possible workaround is to create a custom dialog with a ProgressBar.

Comment: Thanks - yes, that is the workaround I'm using, and it works fine.  But if anyone knows if this is a real feature I'm curious.

Comment: I don't want to bring this post back from the dead, but I'm seeing the same problem, I have a view setup, and try the setview, using the builder, but when it comes up, the screen just fades and I dont' see anything...odd, anyone else know any solutions?